# What will be the best word in this situation?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

He knew it was a very ___ operation but he was determined to carry it out. 
Available options are: 
a) Difficult
b) Dangerous
c) Risky
d) Troublesome

It seems that all the options are valid. Could you please explain, what should be the best answer?

Comment: Exam Qs may be off-topic on ELU.

Comment: Why off topic? I'm asking about usage of the words. Is it really important that it's either from exam question or from real life?

Comment: Please read the FAQ for more details. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

> He knew it was a very ___ operation but he was determined to carry it out.

The key word is *determined*. If something is *dangerous* or *risky*, it would be natural to say you were *willing* in the face of danger. It's unusual to call an operation *troublesome*. But it's normal to say that something is *difficult*, and that your determination for success with be used to overcome that difficulty. So my vote would be for (A) Difficult.

I dislike questions like this, because "best" usually means "everything else is still valid but you should read my mind as to why I think one of these is better".

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context of the person's action. If he were adding a coin to a vending machine, you wouldn't say Risky or dangerous, but you may say difficult or troublesome.